# Como fazer uma div que se expande e mostra o conteúdo oculto?

Tags: html, css

Quero fazer um bloco que expanda para baixo dando informações de festa e eventos, mas estou com muita dificuldade, pois não sei como fazer 2 `div`s ativarem ao mesmo tempo o *mouse over*.

esse é meu código html:

```
<div id="eventos">

<a href="#"><div class="eventos-blocos">
<img src="eventos/a-traidos.jpg" width="250px" height="100px" />
<p align="left">25/02/2014</p><br />
<h3 align="left">A-TRAIDOS</h3>
</div></a>

</div>
```

E esse é o código CSS:

```
#eventos{
    width:810px;
    height:500px;
    background:#666;
    float:left;


}

.eventos-blocos{
    width:250px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#CCC;
    margin:8px;
    border:2px solid #FFF;
    transition:all 700ms;
    -moz-transition:all 700ms;
    -o-transition:all 700ms;
    -webkit-transition:all 700ms;
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;


}

.eventos-blocos:hover{
    border:2px solid #0C9;
    height:150px;


}

.eventos-blocos p{
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
    color:#FFF;
    animation-direction:alternate;
    margin-bottom:-20px;
    margin-left:3px;
    margin-top:3px;
}


.eventos-blocos h3{
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#FFF;
    margin:3px;


}
```

Quando a `div` é acionada pelo *mouseover* a `div` de baixo sempre se afasta demais, parecendo um bug.

Comment: Pode explicar mais detalhadamente o problema, eu coloquei **[teu código no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4vwfjfv2/)** e aparentemente está funcionando corretamente, a única modificação que fiz, foi adicionar um `overflow:hidden` na tua classe `.eventos-blocos`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem o que tu quer, mas se você quer que as informações apareçam quando é acionado o mouseover você deve colocar:

```
**overflow:hidden;**

.eventos-blocos{
width:250px;
height:100px;
float:left;
background-color:#CCC;
margin:8px;
border:2px solid #FFF;
transition:all 700ms;
-moz-transition:all 700ms;
-o-transition:all 700ms;
-webkit-transition:all 700ms;
position:relative;
top:0px;
left:0px;
overflow:hidden;
```

}

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado, consegui.. \õ/